# Program type already present: Google Services Auth

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I've had this problem for several weeks now, and I can't seem to find any solution.

My app worked fine but suddenly it stopped, and can't see any changes in my commit history, so hopefully someone can help me with this.

I'm able to build the project without any errors, but as soon as I try to run it on my phone or in a emulator, it wont and output this error:

```
Program type already present: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My module gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        keyAlias 'key'
        keyPassword 'keypass'
        storePassword 'keypass'
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 27
flavorDimensions "default"
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.bec.bec"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 5
    versionName "1.0.3"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
productFlavors {
    dev {
        applicationIdSuffix ".development"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    prod {
        applicationIdSuffix ".production"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
android.dataBinding.enabled = true
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

// SUPPORT
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'

// GOOGLE SERVICE
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'

// DAGGER 2
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.11'
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17"
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'

// COMPONENTS
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1'

// Retrofit 2
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

// GSON
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'

// PICASSO
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

// FACEBOOK
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'

// FIREBASE
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'

// ROOM
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
kapt 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

// YOUTUBE
implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev193-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}

implementation 'io.github.luizgrp.sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:sectionedrecyclerviewadapter:1.1.3'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'

// TEST
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

// KOTLIN
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Project gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxerrs" << "4000"
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xmaxwarns" << "4000"
        }
    }
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

What I understand is that, the same dependency is implemented multiple times (maybe I'm wrong?) but I can't see where it comes from.
I've tried using 
gradlew app:dependencies
but it does not list my dependencies.

I've tried to change versions of my dependencies, to see if that worked, but it doesn't. I also tried to update the google-services.json file with newest version, but that doesn't seem to help either.
Hope someone can help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it seems that the YouTube dependency where causing the error.
I fixed the error by removing this line in my gradle:

```
implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev193-1.23.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
}
```